# Is there a list or something available which shows the code of the Symbols of Blender

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I'm modifying an Blender addon for my own purpose. Enhancing the usability of my SpacemousePro (If someone would like to have it, no problem).

So I build pie menus for the key of my device. To make it even better I would like to use the inbuild symbols of Blender, but from some like those for the 3D manupulator I don't know how to get the name of the symbols to embed them in my (and some one elses) code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Icon Viewer does exactly what you need. It displays all internal icons in the tool shelf of the text editor. Click on an icon to copy the name.

[image]

[image]

Comment: :-) Nice Theme, looks really like the good old Blender... It's the perfect solution for my case! Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's the "softblend"-theme that comes with blender. :)

Comment: Jepp, I'm also to lazy to change the theme :-)